# Auto-pairs indentation after colon

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

Hitting `<CR>` at `adapters:{|}` gives following

```
//actual behavior
var wtConfig = {
adapters: {  

          }
}

//desire behavior
var wtConfig = {
   adapters: {

   }
}
```

I am running this on vim 7.4 on mac OSX. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Not off-hand - allow me to suggest the dedicated site at https://vi.stackexchange.com/ , which has plenty of wizards :) .

Comment: I am running vanilla MacVim 7.4 patches 1-769 and I get the desired behavior. You may want to try simplifying your vim setup first. Or maybe `vim -u NONE -N -c 'syntax on' -c 'filetype plugin indent on'` to disable your `vimrc`.

Comment: filetype plugin indent on - did the job